# Xpath normalize-space

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm feeling dumb. Python & xpath newbie here. I'm trying to extract the complete text `'Open Box Price: $1079.99'` using xpath from

```
<div class="prod-price">
<p class="opbox-price">
    <strong> Open Box Price:<br>$1079.99</strong>
    </p>
<p class="orig-price">
    Regular Price: <strong>$1499.98</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

But I can't. text stops at `<br>`. Here's my code

```
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)
elements = doc.xpath(item_xpath)
print elements[1].find('div[3]/p[1]/text()[normalize-space()]')
```

Comment: It's not a well-formed document. The `<br>` is not closed as it should be (`<br/>`). XPath is an XML tool, which is less forgiving than browsers.

Comment: @Tom - the OP is using `lxml.html` - so it uses a parser suitable for HTML

Comment: What is the value of `item_xpath`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basis for the XPath you want is using `descendant-or-self` - tweak the result how you want:

```
>>> doc.xpath('//p[1]/descendant-or-self::text()')
['\n    ', ' Open Box Price:', '$1079.99', '\n    ']
>>> doc.xpath('//p[2]/descendant-or-self::text()')
['\n    Regular Price: ', '$1499.98', '\n    ']
```

Or as you're doing with `lxml.html`, you could use `text_content()`

```
paras = doc.xpath('//p'): # or findall etc...
for para in paras:
    print para.text_content()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just use, assuming the initial context (current node) is the parent of `div`:**

```
normalize-space(div/p[1]/strong)
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     "<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(div/p[1]/strong)"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided document corrected to be made well-formed and then enclosed in a top `html` element):

```
<html>
    <div class="prod-price">
        <p class="opbox-price">
          <strong> Open Box Price:<br />$1079.99</strong>
        </p>
        <p class="orig-price">
    Regular Price: 
            <strong>$1499.98</strong>
        </p>
    </div>
</html>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated off the top element (`html`) and the result of the evaluation is copied (enclosed in quotes) to the output**:

```
"Open Box Price:$1079.99"
```